# JAVA object mapper serialization with mixin and changed getter

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm mapping object (**code to which I have no access**) into json using **Jackson Object Mapper** and **MixIn** class. So, for example i have this object:

```
public class Person {
   private String name;
   private String surname;

   public Person (String name, String surname) {
       this.name = name;
       this.surname = surname;
   }

   public String getName() {
       return name;
   }

   public String getSurname() {
       return surname;
   }
}
```

and MixIn class like this:

```
abstract class MixIn {
   @JsonIgnore
   abstract String getSurname(); // we don't need this in json output!
}
```

This working well. But what if i need to change output of `"getName()"` getter to return like `return person.name + " " + person.surname`.

**Is this even possible to do by specific Object Mapper configuration?** (when i have **no access** to Person class code)

Answer (score 4):

You could write a custom serializer:

```
class PersonSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Person> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Person person, JsonGenerator generator, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        generator.writeStartObject();
        generator.writeStringField("name", person.getName() + " " + person.getSurname());
        generator.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

Then, there are multiple ways to register it, for example using a module:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
module.addSerializer(Person.class, new PersonSerializer());
mapper.registerModule(module);

System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(new Person("user", "1827257")));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your code and its working. But what if i have in Person class more properties (age, gender, address, id ....) ? then i need add generator.writeStringField(); for every property which i want in my json output? Can i combine mixin class with my custom serializer?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to serialize the object differently in different cases, so using mixins is preferred:

```
objectMapper.getSerializationConfig().addMixInAnnotations(Person.class, MixIn.class);
String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(new Person("user", "1827257"));
```